# Issue on preview of sitecore page

Tags: sitecore, keystone

I have created template (added placeholder:contentblock) and a site using this template under sitecore->Content.
But on preview of this page, blank page will be displayed without any contents. Even on click of Publish->Experience Editor blank page is displayed without an option to edit contentblock.

Do am missing out any part in between?

Comment: Do you have any layouts/renderings set for this template or item?

Comment: It looks that you are missing something with presentation. You have created the template, but is your page bases that template? Have you set layout file? Is the path to it correct?

Comment: @RubenVerschueren : Yea I had set layout for template but dint work on rendering part. Could you please explain me how to set renderings for template?

Comment: @MartinMiles : What I have done is I have created a template folder under Templates, under this created an template and added _StandardValue. Also set layout and controls (default already existing ContentBlock) for this _StandardValue via Presentation->Details.
Then I have created a site under Content using this template. On preview of home page in this site, blank page can be seen. Its not showing the controls(default already existing ContentBlock) to edit on click of Expeirence Editor.

Comment: @Yasha: Can you see the control in the presentation details of the item itself? including in the final layout? Which version are you working with?
Sitecore 8.0 had a bug that sometimes the renderings weren't set properly on the items, when they were changes on the templates standard values...

Comment: No. under templates _standardvalue i can see control and layout which I selected in the presentation details. But under content-site-home item am not able to view selected controls in the prsentation detail. I am using Sitecore 8

Comment: Thanks Ruben and Martin. I could solve the issue. It was a small setting issue where i had to enable enablePreview.